# Local Notification with UIDatepicker

Tags: ios, notifications, uidatepicker

How I crated local notification for my app and vibrate when the notification show and the user set time for notification with UIDatePicker?

Comment: too broad, please show us where you are and ask a concrete question

Answer (score 0):

register for the UIControlEventValueChanged message from your DatePicker and setup a UILocalNotification then and schedule it